# Uncaught TypeError: setStatusFilters is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

So In my react application I have filtered option dialog. When a user select filter option and there is no related data, the dialog prompts `No objects found based on your filter, try changing filter criteria` and below this text I have a button called `back` to  reset the filters. To do so I have defined a function `resetAllFilters` inside this function I called `setStatusFilters`.

But when I call `resetAllFilters` function I got `Uncaught TypeError: setStatusFilters is not a function at resetAllFilters`

Here is my code.

```
import { Search } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Divider, Grid, List, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";

import TextInput from "../../../components/input/TextInput";
import Loading from "../../../components/loading/Loading";
import { filterObjects, filterSearch } from "../../../data/helpers/Helpers";
import TrackingFilterContainer from "../containers/TrackingFilterContainer";
import ObjectListItem from "./ObjectListItem";
import {
  makeDefaultFilterState,
  makeFilterOptionsObj,
} from "../../../data/helpers/Helpers";
import Button from "../../../components/button/Button";

const classes = {
  Root: {
    height: "100vh",
  },
  SearchInput: (theme) => ({
    mt: "5%",
    // ml: "5%",
    p: 0.7,
    borderRadius: "5px",
    width: "100%",
    bgcolor: "white",
    "& input": {
      overflow: "hidden",
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
    },
    "& svg": {
      mr: "2.5%",
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      mt: 0,
      pl: 1.5,
      bgcolor: "background.primary",
    },
  }),
  SearchLogo: { color: "misc.hint" },
  Divider: (theme) => ({
    mt: "2.5%",
    width: "100%",
    mb: 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      display: "none",
    },
  }),
  FilterWrapper: {
    // mt: "3%",
    px: "2%",
    pt: "5%",
    pb: "3%",
    columnGap: "3%",
  },
  ListWrapper: {
    // mt: "1.5%",
    height: "100%",
    overflow: "auto",
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
      width: "3px",
    },
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
      borderRadius: "8px",
      backgroundColor: "misc.hint",
    },
  },
};

function ObjectList({
  search,
  setSearch,
  trackingObjects,
  loading,
  error,
  selectedObj,
  setSelectedObj,
  statusFilters,
  setStatusCheckboxFilters,
  setStatusFilters,
}) {
  const handleClick = React.useCallback((obj) => {
    setSelectedObj(obj);
  }, []);
  console.log(statusFilters, "object");

  const resultObjs = filterSearch(
    filterObjects(trackingObjects, statusFilters),
    search
  );

  const [res, setReset] = useState(false);
  const reset = () => setReset(!setStatusFilters);
  const objsWithLocations = resultObjs.filter(
    ({ location }) =>
      location?.[0] !== null &&
      location?.[0] !== undefined &&
      location?.[1] !== null &&
      location?.[1] !== undefined
  );

  const defaultFilterState = useMemo(
    () => makeDefaultFilterState(trackingObjects),
    [trackingObjects]
  );
  const filterOptionsObj = useMemo(
    () => makeFilterOptionsObj(trackingObjects),
    [trackingObjects]
  );
  const resetAllFilters = () => {
    setStatusFilters([]);
  };

  // console.log('objsWithLocations', objsWithLocations);

  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" sx={classes.Root} wrap="nowrap">
      <Stack
        sx={{
          flexDirection: { xs: "row", md: "column" },
          alignItems: { xs: "center", md: "flex-start" },
          justifyContent: { xs: "space-between", md: "flex-start" },
          px: 1.0,
          mb: 2,
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          autoComplete="off"
          variant="standard"
          placeholder="Search for an object...."
          value={search}
          onValueChange={setSearch}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <Search sx={classes.SearchLogo} />,
            disableUnderline: true,
          }}
          sx={classes.SearchInput}
        />

        <Divider sx={classes.Divider} />

        <TrackingFilterContainer
          defaultFilterState={defaultFilterState}
          filterOptionsObj={filterOptionsObj}
        />
      </Stack>

      {loading && !resultObjs?.length && <Loading />}

      {error && (
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          color="text.secondary"
          mx="auto"
          mt="5%"
          width="45%"
          textAlign="center"
        >
          {error}
        </Typography>
      )}
      {!loading && objsWithLocations?.length === 0 ? (
        <Typography
          variant="h5"
          color="text.secondary"
          mx="auto"
          mt="5%"
          width="45%"
          textAlign="center"
          //   onClick={() => defaultFilterState()}
        >
          No objects found based on your filter, try changing filter criteria
          <Button
            variant="text"
            text="Back"
            sx={{
              fontSize: "24px",
              p: 0,

              verticalAlign: "baseline",
              ml: "6px",
              textTransform: "none",
            }}
            onClick={() => resetAllFilters()}
          />
        </Typography>
      ) : (
        <List sx={classes.ListWrapper}>
          {objsWithLocations.map((obj) => (
            <ObjectListItem
              key={obj.trackingObjectId}
              object={obj}
              handleClick={handleClick}
              isActive={selectedObj?.trackingObjectId === obj.trackingObjectId}
            />
          ))}
        </List>
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default ObjectList;
// export default React.memo(ObjectList);
```

Here is `ObjectList.js` rendered

```
import {Grid} from "@mui/material";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {useTheme} from "@mui/material/styles";
import useMediaQuery from "@mui/material/useMediaQuery";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {TrackingPageItems} from "../../data/constants/TrackingObject";
import Map from "./map/Map";
import MobileNavigate from "./mobileNavigate/MobileNavigate";
import ObjectList from "./objectList/ObjectList";
import ObjectOne from "./objectOne/ObjectOne";
import buildSocketIoConnection from "../../data/socket.io/client";
import API from "../../data/api/API";
import {handleError} from "../../data/helpers/apiHelpers";
import {checkAuthStatus} from "../../data/helpers/Helpers";
import {filterObjects, filterSearch} from "../../data/helpers/Helpers";


function TrackingPage({
    trackingObjects,
    updateTrackingObjects,
    setTrackingObjects,
    selectedObject,
    setSelectedObject,
    ...props
}) {
    const [objectListSearch, setObjectListSearch] = useState("");
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(TrackingPageItems.LIST);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleTabChange = (newTab) => {
        setSelectedTab(newTab);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const userInfoString = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
        const userInfo = JSON.parse(userInfoString);
        const token = userInfo?.token;
        let possibleSocketIoConnection = null;

        if (token) {
            possibleSocketIoConnection = buildSocketIoConnection(token, updateTrackingObjects);
        } else {
            console.error("No token provided. Won't connect to socket.io server");
        }

        return () => {
            setSelectedObject(null);
            possibleSocketIoConnection?.closeConnection?.();
        };
    }, []);

    const fetchObjectList = React.useCallback((firstTime = false) => {
        firstTime && setLoading(true);
        API.object
            .getObjectList()
            .then((objs) => {
                // console.log('TrackingObjects', objs.data);
                setTrackingObjects(objs.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                checkAuthStatus(err.response?.status, navigate);
                setError(handleError(err, "getObjectList"));
            })
            .finally(() => {
                firstTime && setLoading(false)
            });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchObjectList(!trackingObjects?.length);
        // const interval = setInterval(fetchObjectList, 20000);
        // return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, []);

    const resultObjs = filterSearch(filterObjects(trackingObjects, props.statusFilters), objectListSearch);

    return (
        <>
            <MobileNavigate selectedTab={selectedTab} handleTabChange={handleTabChange} />

            <Grid container direction="row" spacing={1}>
                {(!isMobile || (isMobile && selectedTab === TrackingPageItems.LIST)) && (
                    <Grid item container direction="column" xs={12} md={3}>
                        {selectedObject ? (
                            <ObjectOne trackingObjects={trackingObjects} selectedObj={selectedObject} setSelectedObj={setSelectedObject} />
                        ) : (
                            <ObjectList
                                search={objectListSearch}
                                setSearch={setObjectListSearch}
                                selectedObj={selectedObject}
                                setSelectedObj={setSelectedObject}
                                trackingObjects={trackingObjects}
                                loading={loading}
                                error={error}
                                {...props}
                            />
                        )}
                    </Grid>
                )}

                {(!isMobile || (isMobile && selectedTab === TrackingPageItems.MAP)) && (
                    <Grid item container direction="column" xs={12} md={9}>
                        <Map
                            loading={loading}
                            selectedObj={selectedObject}
                            setSelectedObj={setSelectedObject}
                            trackingObjects={resultObjs}
                            {...props}
                        />
                    </Grid>
                )}
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
}

export default React.memo(TrackingPage);
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you show the code where you render the `ObjectList` component?

Comment: @AhmadFaraz functions can be converted to a boolean.

Comment: @User456 I updated my code and added the component where ObjectList rendered

Comment: @TeshAych Do you pass `setStatusFilters` prop to `TrackingPage`?

Comment: @User456 I imported setStatusFilters. and here is the code. `export const setStatusFilters = (statusFilters) => ({
    type: TrackingObjectsActionTypes.SET_STATUS_FILTERS,
    payload: { statusFilters },
});`

Comment: Where did you import it?